# Identifying markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

> **Problem:** A regular dice is thrown repeatedly. Which one of the following random variables with values in $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}\cup\{0\}$ is a Markov chain? For those who are, give the transition matrix:
>   1) The largest number up to the $n$-th throw
>   2) The number of fives up to the $n$-th throw
>   3) The time since the last 3 occured
>   4) The time until the next 1 occures

**My attempt:**  I think it is implicitly assumed that the dice throws are independent. I am going to write $p_{ij}(n)$ for the transition matrix from state $i$ to state $j$.

1) This is a time-homogeneous Markov chain, since it only depends on the state directly before it (the state before "contains" the information of the past in some sense). The probabilities are given by 
$p_{ij} =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{l1}
  0  & j \lt i \\
  \dfrac{i}{6} & i = j \\
        \dfrac{1}{6} & j \gt i
 \end{array}
\right.$

2) This again is a time-homogeneous Markov chain, same reasoning as above, probabilities $p_{ij} =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{l1}
  \dfrac{5}{6} & i = j \\
        \dfrac{1}{6} & j = i+1 \\
  0  & otherwise
 \end{array}
\right.$

3) I'm assuming time here means the number of throws. This is also a time-homogeneous Markov chain, again same reasoning as for 1 and 2. probabilities $p_{ij} =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{l1}
  \dfrac{1}{6}  & j = 0  \\
        \dfrac{5}{6} & j = i+1 \\
        0 & otherwise
 \end{array}
\right.$

4) I have no clue here. This doesn't even depend on the past, it depends on the future, so it has no chance to be a Markov chain.

I'm not entirely sure how I would go about formally reasoning that my clains are true. I think finding a transition matrix is enough to show that it is a Markov chain, since it directly gives us the stochastic kernel. How am I supposed to reason for 4)?

Comment: Hint about 4.: The only nonzero transitions are $p_{0,i}$ and $p_{i+1,i}$ for $i\geqslant0$.

Comment: You need to be careful about your intuitive reasoning in problem 4. The quantity of interest depends on the future of your dice rolling experiment, yes, but that's not important. What matters is how the quantity depends on its *own* past. And as Did pointed out, there are only two possibilities: either you didn't just have a $1$, in which case the time goes down by $1$, or you did just have a $1$, in which case the time is now an independent geometric random variable. Either way you can completely specify the distribution at the next time by knowing the value at the current time.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was thinking in terms of the die throws themselves, not the random variables. So would it be enough for me to specifiy the transition matrix to verify that it is indeed a Markov chain?

Comment: Yes: if you can specify a transition matrix, then you have a Markov chain, since the transition matrix says that the probability distribution of $X_n$ is completely determined by the value of $X_{n-1}$. Specifically, it is the $(X_{n-1})$th row of the transition matrix. (Note that in problems 2-4, the transition "matrix" is not really a matrix, since it has infinitely many rows and columns.)

Comment: By the way, +1 for showing your work, I really appreciate that.

Comment: One thing about Markov chains is that if you reverse them in time, you still have a markov chain (albeit with a different transition matrix).

Comment: @Batman The definition of the time reversal that I know of uses the invariant distribution. Can you elaborate on what happens when no such distribution exists?

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to state that part -- I was just saying that the logic for #4 doesn't necessarily hold water.